# ASP.NET MVC 5 share bundles between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, bundling-and-minification

I have 3 projects under my solution:

- Account
- Management
- Domain

Account and Management are MVC 5 applications. Account sits on the root directory within IIS (http://localhost/) and Management sits as an application within that (http://localhost/Management). Domain is a class library so I can share a database context between them.

I'm using bundles to serve my JS and CSS files. Below is a snippet from App_Start/BundleConfig.cs within the Account application.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bool developerMode = Environment.MachineName != "LIVE_MACHINE";
    string libScriptsDirectory = "~/Public/scripts/lib/";
    string libStylesDirectory = "~/Public/styles/lib/";

    string[] libScripts = new string[]
    {
        libScriptsDirectory + (developerMode == true ? "vue-2.5.17.dev.js" : "vue-2.5.17.min.js"),
        libScriptsDirectory + "vuetify-1.3.1.js",
        libScriptsDirectory + "vue-resource-1.5.1.js",
        libScriptsDirectory + "vue-snotify-3.2.1.js",
        libScriptsDirectory + "moment-2.22.2.js"
    };

    string[] libStyles = new string[]
    {
        libStylesDirectory + "material-41.css",
        libStylesDirectory + "font-awesome-4.7.0.css",
        libStylesDirectory + "vuetify-1.3.1.css",
        libStylesDirectory + "vue-snotify-3.2.1.css"
    };

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib.min.js").Include(libScripts));
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/lib.min.css").Include(libStyles));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = !developerMode;
}
```

This works perfectly fine with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib.min.js")` within the Account application and I can even do `@Scripts.Render("/bundles/lib.min.js")` within the Management application. The only problem with this is I would like to utilise `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` when I am within a development environment. This is possible under the Account application as when this is set to false, I am given all of my JS and CSS files unbundled but this is not the case for the Management application as I am not referencing a virtual path, so it'll always retrieve the bundled version.

I don't particularly want to have two sets of the same code that do the same thing. Is there any way I can have one place where my static JS and CSS files are and utilise bundling within both applications to serve bundled *and* unbundled files? It's within my understanding that bundles don't allow absolute paths so I know that's not an option.

Comment: The issue is when `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` is set to true or false?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a virtual directory pointing to the absolute path of the JS and CSS files that I wanted to use. I added this virtual directory into each application, so /Lib/... works and /Management/Lib/... works.